# Getting `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification: nokogiri-1.6.7.2> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I created a rails app and then import Gemfile from another app including spec files. When I run rspec I get following errors. What I am doing wrong?

My Gemfile is below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.4'
gem 'poltergeist', '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'phantomjs', '~> 1.9.8.0'

group :development, :test do
 gem 'byebug'
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

 gem 'spring'
end

gem 'httparty'
```

My spec_helper.rb is below:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

The error I am seeing below:

```
/Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2157:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fed45440788 nokogiri-1.6.7.2> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1056:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:63:in `require'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:119:in `require'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:119:in `require'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capybara-2.6.0/lib/capybara.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from /Users/subratrout/rails_projects/recipefindern/spec/spec_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:101:in `setup'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have Nokogiri gem installed?

Comment: Are you running Rails on Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error.
It  was strange, because in other similar project rspec was working fine.
I installed older version of ruby (2.2.3) with rvm, installed gems and it worked.

```
rvm install ruby-2.2.3
rvm ruby-2.2.3
gem install rspec
gem install rspec-its
gem install capybara
gem install poltergeist
```

and then rspec started to work.

Please write if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is to delete Gemfile.lock file and then do bundle install. Somehow the new Ruby version was having conflict with Nokogiri version 1.6.7.2.